# Substitute for Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# batch job that needs to connect to an .xslx Excel spreadsheet. On my windows 7 machine, the provider in the connection string is specified as such:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0
```

However, when to job is moved onto the server it will be running on, I get the following error message:

```
System Exception: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.;
```

The server is running Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 2. Does anyone know of a provider that will work on this machine given that the spreadsheet is (and will always be) a 2010 Excel .xslx spreadsheet?

Comment: You'll need to install ACE on that server.  And you need to set the EXE project's Target platform setting to x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps:

- http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007 (works also for 2010)
- http://www.xporttools.net/ (3rd party xls(x) provider)

Comment: System requirements
Supported operating systems: Windows 7, *Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-Bit x86)*, Windows Server 2003 R2 x64 editions, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista Service Pack 1, Windows XP Service Pack 3
Hope it works